# How to convert Optional Double to Double in javafx

Tags: javafx, option-type

The following code if compiled gives the following error. How to solve this

*error: incompatible types: OptionalDouble cannot be converted to Double
                                         .average();*

```
  Double todaypctpnl = openPositionsdata.stream()
                                     .mapToDouble(c->Double.parseDouble(c.getTodaypctpnl()))
                                     .average();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you take a look at the API docs for [OptionalDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html)?

There are several ways how to convert it back to a `double` value, like for example:

- `double value = OptionalDouble.orElse(-1)`
- `double value = OptionalDouble.orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new)`

etc.

You will have to choose the one fitting best your current needs.

Comment: Thank you that helped solve the problem OptionalDouble     todaypctpnl =  values.stream()
                                  .mapToDouble(c->Double.parseDouble(c.getTodaypctpnl()))
                                  .average();
Double  todaypctpnlDbl  = todaypctpnl.getAsDouble();

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

`Double todaypctpnl = openPositionsdata.stream()
.mapToDouble(c->Double.parseDouble(c.getTodaypctpnl()))
                                     .average().getAsDouble();`